# Error while subscribing from http request angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, subscribe

I'm working on the test driven angular app. (Don't ask why, That is how client wants)

Below is the spec which I can't `modify` or `edit`.

```
  it('should get results', fakeAsync(
    inject(
      [XHRBackend, NewsService ],
      (mockBackend: MockBackend, newsService: NewsService) => {

      const expectedUrl = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=315a5a51483b469a918246dc2753b339';

      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection : MockConnection) => {
          expect(connection.request.method).toBe(RequestMethod.Get);
          expect(connection.request.url).toBe(expectedUrl);

          connection.mockRespond(new Response(
            new ResponseOptions({ body: mockResponse })
          ));
        });

      newsService.getSectionNews('home')
        .subscribe( (res: any) => {
            expect(res).toEqual(mockResponse);
        });
    })
  ));
```

So based on the spec, I need to write my front end code.

So this is what I've written,

```
  import { Http } from '@angular/http';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getSectionNews(sectionName: string): any {
    // fetch news of that sectionName
   // return this.mockResponse;
   const expectedUrl = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=315a5a51483b469a918246dc2753b339';
   return this.http.get(expectedUrl).subscribe(res => res);
  }
```

But while running the test case, I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: newsService.getSectionNews(...).subscribe is not a function

please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

I wanted to pass the test case.

**UPDATE**

After updating my service spec.

```
  getSectionNews(sectionName: string): Observable<any> {
    const expectedUrl = `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/${sectionName}.json?api-key=315a5a51483b469a918246dc2753b339`;
    return this.http.get(expectedUrl);
  }
```

Now I'm getting this below error,

> Expected Response with status: null null for URL: null to equal
>   Objectt({ status: 'OK', copyright: 'C ...

Comment: Just don't subscribe to it inside `getSectionNews`

Comment: By subscribing Observable when returning it, you will return subscription and subscription have no subscribe method.

Comment: but without subscribing, how will I return the data ?

Comment: You subscribing whenever You want to get data. So in spec file or component.ts or component.html.

Comment: If only spec file use `getSectionNews()` it should be ok i dont see any more code were you use `getSectionNews()`

Comment: spec should get passed. But with my current code I'm getting error while running spec

Comment: It is not some Test for You to pass with this spec files ?

Comment: its kind of my school homework :-D

Comment: Show me from where did You import `this.http`

Comment: The problem is You are not getting data from `this.http.get(..)`

Comment: I've updated my ques, added the import statements

Answer (score 0):

getSectionNews(sectionName: string): Observable {
// fetch news of that sectionName
this.apiURL = `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/${sectionName}.json?api-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`;
return this.http.get(this.apiURL).map((res) => res.json());
}

Above shared code will resolve this issue. Thanks